# Is it ok to create multiple instance of the Sound libgdx

Tags: java, audio, libgdx

Should I use multiple Sound instance, or have one Sound instance and make use of `long id` which is returned by play ? What are use cases of that id from `Sound.play()` ? Is it possible to play multiple sounds within the same time and instance by using different id or I should load that id into new Sound instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just have the one instance. If you call play() and then call it again before the first call has finished playing, it doesn't stop the first one - both sounds will now be playing. You can call play() as many times as you like.

The id that play() returns is used to identify the instance of the sound that is playing, so it will be different for every call to play(). You can then use the id in other methods (like stop() for example) to control just that one instance of the sound.

Comment: So, I load one sound, play it, get ID, save that ID... then play another sound the same way, and after that I get sound one ID, put in the play, and it will load that sound one, correct ?

Comment: The id is used for when you're playing the same sound more than once at the same time. Let's say you load a long sound, then call play() and remember the id. Then a second later you call play() the same sound again at the same time, so the sound is now playing twice (like an echo). If you use the first id in the stop() method, then the sound from the first call to play() will stop playing immediately, but the second one will still be playing.